# In Windows, how can I termiante an application if I can't get the task manager to the foreground?

Tags: windows, process, crash, terminate, taskmanager

Basically the question is what is the Windows equivalent to Linux' changing tty, login in and killing processes from there?

Situation: Once in a while I switch back to Windows to play games when there seems no reasonable way to get them running under Linux. Problem is, that some of these games tend to crash frequently (screen freeze). However, when I try to open the task manager, I will get a black screen or simply cannot get out of the game, requiring me to restart my computer.
Being a while into Linux, were you are usually not required to restart just because of unimportant applications, I figured that Windows might have considered the problem, too.
Might be I want to run another important application in background that should not stop during playtime.

**tl;dr How to kill processes in windows when it's not possible to switch to Task Manager rsp. Alt-Tab to any other window?**

**Edit:**
What I already tried, but did not work ingame:

Try go get to cmd/taskmanager:

- `Ctrl+Alt+Del` <-- proves that the machine is still responsive as it does switch to the menu where I can select task manager, but once I click I just get a task bar with black windows above or the frozen game screen, but no working window...
- `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`
- `Win+x`
- `Win+r`

Try to exit application:

- `Alt+F4`
- `press red X-button at right corner` (not responsive when frozen)

Try to switch to other windows:

- `Alt+Tab`

Open new virtual desktop:

- `Win+Tab`
- `Ctrl+Win+Tab`

It seems, Windows key bindings are context-sensitive. Any other options how to force quit an unresponsive application?

What would (probably) work:

- `Switch user` via `Ctrl+Alt+Del` (but it seems excessive to create another user just for the purpose of killing a process)
- `sign out, sign in` (but this also closes applications that should still be responsive, which is what I want to avoid, but at least better than a full restart)

What I will try out next time the application freezes:

- `Task Manager -> Options > Always on Top`
- I created a shortcut for `C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /f /fi "status eq not responding"` which I pinned to taskbar, will try out if I can access that on freeze

Answer (score 2):

If the machine is responsive, you can Ctrl+Shift+Esc to get to task manager and At+F, Alt+N to start a new task, run cmd, and you have a new terminal. Then you can run taskkill /f /IM as needed.

Comment: Even though I appreciate the answer (didn't know there's a shortcut) it doesn't work even when the application does not hang. `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` will work from desktop, but not ingame, and I simply cannot switch to Task Manager/cmd once the game is open, using the common way  (the TaskManager opens, but remains in background, can't get to cmd from there) :/ Figured `Windows+R` would be a faster way, still the problem I can't interact with the window.

Comment: I figured it out, building up on your command, you may consider adding that to the answer and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

For freezes where it is not possible to interact with application windows anymore, but the task bar still showing up, this seems to be a reliable, generic and easy-to-do solution:

-> Pinning a shortcut to the taskbar, containing the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /f /fi "status eq not responding"
```

Also, its possible to modify settings of Task manager to have them always on top:

```
Task Manager -> Options > Always on Top
```